# is it possible to find the javascript that is setting an element attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

is it possible to find the javascript that is setting an element attribute in chrome dev tools? or any other tool ?

## Example:

Javascript set href in some external file

```
$('.buy_button').attr('href','asdf');
```

...then inside the main.html

```
<a href="asdf" class="buy_button">the link</a>
```

How do I find what is setting `main.html` in chrome dev tools or some other tool ?

Comment: Why not just look through the external JavaScript file for where it's changing the attribute? How big is the JavaScript file? Are you the author of these files?

Comment: arer u looking for this <a href="#" class="buy_button">the link</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually it IS possible:

- locate the element you need to check (in 'Elements' tab)
- open the context menu for that element (right-click on it)
- choose 'Break on...', check 'Attributes modification' option

... and the script will pause (go into `debugger` mode) when attributes of that element are modified.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not possible, you should go inside the javascript scripts and search it by your own. You should search for something like the id of the element, or the `.attr()` function and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If you know what element type or class the JavaScript is hitting then you can open up that JS file in chrome or another IDE and just match the text to the class or element type that the JS is modifying.

The example on the first part of your example will hit anything with the class of buy_button so searching that would be a good start.  You can open the JavaScript files inside of the Chrome inspection tool by finding them in the head tag and clicking on them.  Once they are opened, you can then click anywhere and use CTRL+F to search for the class.